# Camel Body null check for a particular field is failing

Tags: apache-camel

This is my apache camel route  where I am null checking for a particular 
field in the body of the camel but I am getting a `SimpleIllegalSyntaxException`.

```
     <choice>
        <when>
          <simple>${body} != null</simple>
            <log message="body field is not null" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="body field is null" />
        </otherwise>
     </choice>
```

For the following route I am getting the following error:

Caused by:

```
org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: 
expected symbol whiteSpace
```

How ever I am able to get value of `<log message="body not null: ${body[CDR_JSON_FORM]}"/>` in the log.

I am trying to get a row from the table `<from uri="sql:{{sql.RecycleHBRSelectQuery}}"/>` and the idea to check to if a particular field from the row extracted is null or not.

Comment: Are you sure you have spaces around the != operator? And what version of Camel do you use?